# Why i get 0 results in query(one row in table have search word)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[**STRUCTURE TABLES AND SQL QUERY ON SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/299fd/4)

Table Price:

```
name  id_firm  id_city  name
ООО   1429     73041    ПЕРЕВОЗКА ГРУЗА (ГРУЗОПЕРЕВОЗКА) АВТО 
ООО   1429     73041    ПЕРЕВОЗКА ГРУЗА (ГРУЗОПЕРЕВОЗКА) АВТО 
ООО   1429     73041    ПЕРЕВОЗКА ГРУЗА (ГРУЗОПЕРЕВОЗКА) АВТО 
ООО   1429     73041    ПЛИТКА КЕРАМИЧЕСКАЯ ГРАНИТ (КЕРАМОГРАНИТ) АССОРТ.
ООО   1429     73041    РАБОТЫ ГРУЗОПОДЪЕМНЫЕ АВТОВЫШКА (ПОДЪЕМНИК)
ООО   1429     73041    РАБОТЫ ГРУЗОПОДЪЕМНЫЕ АВТОКРАНОМ Г/П 25Т
ООО   1429     73041    РАБОТЫ КОМПРЕССОРОМ ВСЕ ВИДЫ
ООО   1429     73041    РАБОТЫ ПОГРУЗОЧНО-РАЗГРУЗОЧНЫЕ АВТОКРАНОМ-МАНИПУЛЯТОРОМ
```

i use query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  Row_Number()OVER(PARTITION BY f.name ORDER BY f.priority, d.end_date, p.datetime DESC) AS NameOrder, 
    p.id_price as p_id_price,
    p.id_service as p_id_service,
    p.name as p_name,
    p.name_original as p_name_original,
    p.id_producer_country as p_id_producer_country,
    p.id_firm as p_id_firm,
    p.unit as p_unit,
    f.name as f_name,
    f.priority as f_priority,
    f.address as f_address,
    f.phone as f_phone,
    city.name as city_name,
    pc.name as pc_name
FROM Price p
    left join Firm f on f.id_service = p.id_service AND f.id_city = p.id_city AND f.id_firm = p.id_firm
    left join City city on city.id_city = p.id_city
    left join Producer_country pc on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country
    left join Dogovor d on d.id_service=p.id_service AND d.id_city=p.id_city AND d.id_firm=p.id_firm
WHERE 
    p.name LIKE '%АВТОВЫШКА%'
)
AS S WHERE S.NameOrder = 1
ORDER BY S.f_priority DESC
```

But i get 0 results.

Tell me please why i get 0 results when i search `АВТОВЫШК_ (%` if table have row `ООО    1429     73041    РАБОТЫ ГРУЗОПОДЪЕМНЫЕ АВТОВЫШКА (ПОДЪЕМНИК)`

Why count rows in results is 0?

Comment: What happens if you just type `select * from price where p.name LIKE '%АВТОВЫШКА%'`?

Comment: what happens if you update that row and change name to something like "AUTO" and then run query for '%AUTO%' .. in this case it works? (your select looks ok)

Comment: @Zane result query `select * from price where p.name LIKE '%АВТОВЫШКА%'` is 1 row with this word

Comment: @learner what do you get if you remove `WHERE S.NameOrder = 1`?

Comment: @Zane i would like get only one product for each firm

Comment: peoples, i add link on structure tables and result query on [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/299fd/4) in start question. check please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clause `LIKE 'АВТОВЫШК %'` means that the value of that column for the current row has to *start with* that string. If you want to match it *anywhere* in the string you need an "any number of characters" wildcard on both ends:

```
LIKE '%АВТОВЫШК %'
```

Comment: sorry - i write not right in `WHERE` i use `WHERE p.name LIKE '%АВТОВЫШКА%'` but i get 0 results.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid as OP clarified this was not the issue.

Comment: i add link on structure tables and result query on [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/299fd/4) in start question. check please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that because of your language encoding you are storing p.name as an `NVARCHAR(xx)` datatype.

The string you are passing in with `LIKE '%АВТОВЫШК %'` is effectively a `VARCHAR`, so all the special characters are lost and so the strings don't match.

Try specifying it like this:

```
LIKE N'%АВТОВЫШК%'
```

Adding the N to the start of the string tells SQL server that it is a unicode string and so the special characters will be preserved, then you have a better chance of matching.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid as OP clarified this was not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You write that your table is like this:

Table Price:

```
name  id_firm  id_city  name
ООО   1429     73041    ПЕРЕВОЗКА ГРУЗА (ГРУЗОПЕРЕВОЗКА) АВТО 
ООО   1429     73041    РАБОТЫ ГРУЗОПОДЪЕМНЫЕ АВТОВЫШКА (ПОДЪЕМНИК)
ООО   1429     73041    РАБОТЫ ГРУЗОПОДЪЕМНЫЕ АВТОКРАНОМ Г/П 25Т
```

As you can see in this table you have column with name **name** twice.
Are you sure that the second column (used in where) is not "name_original"?

Your select looks ok, if you have correct encoding in select and also in databas,
I don´t see any problem.

Comment: first `name` - it `f.name`